# How to call function when I choose line from ComboBox in C++?

Tags: c++, .net, combobox

I wanted to call function by choosing line from ComboBox, but I don't know how to write it properly

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBox1Change(TObject *Sender) {
if (ComboBox1.Lines.Count == 1) {
    mode = 1;
}
else if (ComboBox1.Lines.Count == 2) {
    mode = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check value of `ComboBox::SelectedIndex` property if it is Visual C++. 
**Check value of `TComboBox::ItemIndex` field if it is Embarcadero C++ Builder.**

Depending on the value of this property take appropriate action.